# Jquery Checked Selector

Tags: jquery, selector, checked

I am deleting table rows with this jquery code as seen on screenshot.

```
$(":checked").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove()
});
```

[image]

When i check the checkbox in th tag and click delete also this first tr row deleted. I select all checkbox with this code $(":checked") How can select after first checkbox ?

Comment: using `.parent().parent()` is very brittle and will break if you change your HTML structure. If you're trying to find the `tr`, you should use `.parent('tr')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(":checked").filter(":not(:eq(0))").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove()
});
```

Alternatively, if your table header is inside the `thead` tag and your body was in the `tbody` tag, you could use something like this:

```
$("tbody tr :checked").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6njSr/)

```
$(":checked").not(':eq(0)').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove()
});
```

Comment: @CihanKüsmez, there's another answer if you haven't noticed it. Which in your bootstrap-esque setup should work

Answer (score 0):

Add a class on first checkbox, by which all checkboxes are checked/unchecked on click event.

In this way, all other checkboxed will be differentiated from first one.

And use following script.

```
$(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        $(":checked").not('.maincheckbox').each(function() {
           $(this).parent().parent().remove()
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the Demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeEcC/%E2%80%8B)